# Apply another gulp plugin in my own gulp plugin using through2

Tags: gulp, through2

I am writing my own gulp plugin which looks like this...

```
var through2 = require('through2');
var order = require('gulp-order');

module.exports = function() {
    return through2.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {
        callback(null, transform(file));
    });
};

function transform(file) {
    // I will modify file.contents here - its ok
    return file;
}
```

and I would like to apply some other gulp plugin on my buffer which came from gulp.src. Is it possible using through2? For example before calling through2.obj() I would like to apply gulp-order plugin - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to chain different gulp plugins together [`lazypipe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe) is generally is good option:

```
var through2 = require('through2');
var order = require('gulp-order');

function yourPlugin()
    return through2.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {
        callback(null, transform(file));
    });
}

function transform(file) {
    // I will modify file.contents here - its ok
    return file;
}

function orderPlugin()
    return order(['someFolder/*.js', 'someOtherFolder/*.js']);
}

module.exports = function() {
   return lazypipe().pipe(orderPlugin).pipe(yourPlugin)();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm! Is there some solution to process buffer two times. E.g. I have 3 files in buffer (from gulp.src) A, B and C and I have 2 plugins functions yourPlugin1 and yourPlugin2. Using lazy pipe files will be processed in this order yourPlugin1:A, yourPlugin2:A, yourPlugin1:B, yourPlugin2:B, yourPlugin1:C, yourPlugin2:C. I would like to get yourPlugin1:A, yourPlugin1:B, yourPlugin1:C and then yourPlugin2:A, yourPlugin2:B, yourPlugin2:C.

Comment: That's a new question. Make a new post.